# Type=text pattern issue with special characters

Tags: java, javascript, html, xhtml

I have created a 
type=text pattern="abc.*|123.*" for a personal mini project but this is for my user id field.

Is there anyway i can add a pattern type to restrict the use of Symbols or Special characters in my Password field?  And a minimum of ONE Uppercase letter?
I have tried using ~NOT JavaScript but i am unsure if this is the right or easy solution.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Mike R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try String.prototype.match().  You could use the appropriate regular expression as the argument of match().  If you want to ensure that the string has exactly one non-alphanumeric character, the regular expression would be /\w*[^\w]\w*/ .

This is one or more alphanumeric characters followed by one non-alphanumeric character, followed by zero or more alphanumeric characters.

For example, the command:

```
'abc643%5#4'.match(/\w*[^\w]\w*/)
```

returns the following.

```
[ 'abc643%5',
  index: 0,
  input: 'abc643%5#4' ]
```

You could use this to create any number of tests on the input string.

Comment: Thanks you are awesome!  What if I wanted the form field to NOT allow any non alphanumeric characters?  Would i just tweek the code as such?

Comment: If you wanted only alphanumeric characters, the regular expression would be /\w*/